# Ubuntu TestContainers unable to connect to Postgis:9.5

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, testcontainers

I have the following definition of `TestContainers` (version 1.12.2) module prepared to test liquibase schema in our app. When trying to execute I'm receiving `Connection Refused` error like it would not exist, however during run of the test I've checked containers and their up:

```
private static final String DB_URL = String.format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%s/%s", "localhost", 5432, DB_NAME);

    @Rule
    public final GenericContainer<?> container = 
            new GenericContainer<>("mdillon/postgis:9.5")
                .withExposedPorts(5432)
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_USER", USER)
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", PASSWORD)
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_DB", DB_NAME);

    @Test
    public void transactionSchemaWasUpdated() throws Exception {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
            // GIVEN
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
            database.setDefaultSchemaName(SCHEMA);
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("install.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
            liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("schemaName", SCHEMA);
            // WHEN
            liquibase.update("main");
            // THEN
            assertEquals(getAppVersion(), getDbVersion(connection));
        }
    }
```

`Docker ls` result during run of tests:

```
378e828e4149        mdillon/postgis:9.5                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:32784->5432/tcp   thirsty_stonebraker
6a270c963322        quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3   "/app"                   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:32783->8080/tcp   testcontainers-ryuk-78a4fc8d-4fb9-41bf-995f-b31076b02465
```

Error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a port is exposed in testcontainers, it actually does not use the same port, but another one. [According docs](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/):

> From the host's perspective Testcontainers actually exposes this on a
>   random free port. This is by design, to avoid port collisions that may
>   arise with locally running software or in between parallel test runs.

You need to ask the container for the mapped port:

```
Integer actualPostgresPort = container.getMappedPort(5432);
```

If you analyze the output of `docker ps`, you will see that port 5432 is not being exposed, but 32784 instead.

Comment: It is kinda weird, because I switched from windows 10 to ubuntu two days ago and it worked on W10, no idea why it started to fail now, since I had almost the same mapping from `docker container ls`.

Comment: Edit.
It is possible I had postgres installed on my Win10 Machine. This is the reason it worked.